# peace lily problem

Tags: plant-health

I have a peace lily which is 6 weeks old (part of a sympathy planter), I transplanted it last week into a larger pot since it was beginning to droop and yellow.  I used Miracle Grow potting soil, watered and put a touch of leaf shine on  the leaves.  It is drooping more, I have removed all the "bad" leaves once again, moved it from indirect to more direct light.  Can you help me? I really don't want to lose this plant. Thank you.

Comment: So you moved it from direct sunlight to indirect sunlight and it started to droop? If that's the case, now that you have moved it back, it should perk up in the next few days.

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: Hello Linda & Welcome.   You can add a picture by first hitting the edit link.  Then above where you write your answer hit the 6th icon from the left, a mountain w/a sun, then hit browse to find the picture on your device.   Select your image, hit open, then add picture/image.   We want to help you, just need more input.  Thank you.